# Space in between buttons

Tags: css

'm totally new here.  I just started with the headline and bumbed into first issue: I can not get any space between the buttons . Using justify-content: space-between in any possible way. See code below. Now the buttons are far from eachother by using space-between. How can I keep the buttons to the right with  some space between the buttons? Thx'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <!--==================== UNICONS paste link from iconscout.com====================-->

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">

  <!--==================== SWIPER CSS====================

    check whether I need to use swiper bundle.css or  If I don't want to include Swiper

     files in my project, I may use it from CDN:
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
-->
```

```
<title>Y.Eser Stukadoors Schilderwerk | Professionele stukadoorsbedrijf Nederland</title>

<!--=======================Header Logo=================================-->
<header class="header" id="header">
    <nav class="nav container">
        <a href="#" class="nav__logo">eigen logo hier</a>
```

```
<div class="btn">




    <div style = "display: flex; justify-content:flex-end; justify-content:space-between">
    <button>




        <a href="tel:+31064301327"><strong>Bel ons</strong>    


        
    </button>



    <br>
    <button>



        <a href="eser.yusuf58@hotmail.com"><strong>Mail ons</strong>
        </a>



    </button>
</div>


</div>
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In flexbox, `justify-content: space-between` will always fix the two outermost elements to the edges of the container.  You also have `justify-content` defined twice, so the later value is overriding the earlier value.

You may be better served removing that and applying a margin to the buttons instead.  For example, set the "Mail ons" button to have `margin-left: 20px` or something to that equivalent.

```html
<div class="btn">
    <div style = "display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
      <button>
          <a href="tel:+31064301327"><strong>Bel ons</strong>    
      </button>
      <button style="margin-left: 20px;">
        <a href="eser.yusuf58@hotmail.com"><strong>Mail ons</strong></a>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a good explainer on how flexbox works](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background).

Comment: Somehow I missed email-notification. Thank you for your clear answer. Make sense. Also thanks for the link, useful information. I have achieved online certification for front-end, but putting it into practise is so different. Small issues come up.

Comment: @Yazzy Happy to help! Flexbox can be tricky to wrap your head around at first. I recommend building a sample page for yourself with examples of each property for future reference. 

Please mark my answer as accepted if you feel it resolves your question :)